# Publishing GITLAB issues via Jekyll

Tags: gitlab, jekyll

One of the institutes I am working for provides a GITLAB instance through which we can create Jekyll deployments from within our GITLAB groups.

My colleagues and I are now wondering if there is some way to integrate issues (in which we collect user stories) directly into the Jekyll site.

This will most likely not be possible, though, as issues cannot be made public in an otherwise private repository: cf. [this discussion in the GITLAB FORUM](http://%20https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-make-wiki-and-issue-management-public-in-a-private-repository/281/6).

Alternatively, we would like to know if there is a model workflow for exporting the issues (as CSV?) and fluidly integrating them into the .md or .html pages of the Jekyll repo. As the issues are continuously updated, we would like to reflect changes on the fly. I suppose some JS pipeline could work?

Links to resources are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In general, any integration you want to do with project issues is definitely *possible* using a JavaScript and [OAuth authentication](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html#supported-oauth-20-flows) with a frontend app. Pages sites can also be configured to respect membership settings. See [pages access control](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/pages_access_control.html). Though, you'd probably have to build the integration yourself, which could be challenging without some JS/frontend experience.

If you just want to *view* your issues in your pages site, you can always pull the issue information at build time, like you described, then no OAuth or js is necessarily needed. However, your docs may become stale unless you rebuild very often (probably not ideal, given your objectives). You could use [scheduled pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) to potentially overcome this if you're okay with the pages being stale between scheduled runs.

Comment: The scheduled pipelines sound like a good idea. Updating in longer intervals would be perfectly fine. I spoke to the IT Services at my uni, too, and they said a last resort would be having all the user stories in an entirely public repo. That would require some visibility wrangling of all the repos in our group as the group itself is private, so I will try an API + JS solution first.